# Case Statement adding instead of subtracting

Tags: sql

I have a case statement as part of a much larger query.

```
CASE 
   WHEN #TAB.PEND_ORDER = #TAB2.PEND_ORDER AND SUM_OVERPMT > 0 
     THEN (#TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT - (SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT - SUM_OVERPMT))
   WHEN #TAB.PEND_ORDER = #TAB2.PEND_ORDER AND SUM_OVERPMT IS NULL 
     THEN (#TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT - SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT)
END AS 'BALANCE'
```

In this section,

```
 CASE 
    WHEN #TAB.PEND_ORDER = #TAB2.PEND_ORDER AND SUM_OVERPMT > 0 
      THEN (#TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT - (SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT - SUM_OVERPMT))
```

it's adding the `SUM_OVERPMT` instead of subtracting it.

Example:

- `#TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT` is **156.25**
- `SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT` is **162.36**
- `SUM_OVERPMT` is **133.90**

My balance should be **-140.01** but instead I'm getting **127.29**.

Comment: Example - #TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT is 156.25.  SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT is 162.36.  SUM_OVERPMT is 133.90.  My balance should be -140.01 but instead I'm getting 127.29.

Comment: Looks like my parens are in the wrong place.  I'll try changing that.

Comment: Changing my parens fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: As Amit pointed, 1 - (1-1) = 1 so remove the parens ` #TAB.OUTBND_837_CLM_BILL_AMT - SUM_835_CLM_PAID_AMT - SUM_OVERPMT`

Comment: Case expression - as it's a part of a query! (Case statement is a stored procedure construction.)

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are wrong. Remove the inner brackets and try this instead:

```
DECLARE @sum_overpmt float = 133.90, 
        @sum_835_clm_paid_amt float = 162.36, 
        @outbnd_837_clm_bill_amt float = 156.25    

SELECT CASE WHEN @sum_overpmt > 0 
            THEN (@outbnd_837_clm_bill_amt - @sum_835_clm_paid_amt - @sum_overpmt) 
        END -- Result: -140.01
```